# Django 1054 Unknown Field error

Tags: django, foreign-keys, migration

I'm attempting to add a new foreign key to an existing model of mine, but I'm having issues getting it to save the values from the UI.  When I get to the relevant page, the data populates correctly, but when I attempt to save a change of the foreign key I get a 1054 "Unknown column 'schedule_id' in 'field list'" error.  Strangely, if I refresh the page, the changes were saved regardless of the error.

Relevant models:

```
class Group(BaseModel):
    code = CharField()
    name = CharField()
    calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar)
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, null=True, blank=True, default=None) # this is the new FK

class Schedule(BaseModel):
    code = CharField()
    name = CharField()
    description = CharField()
    #various integer fields
```

I'm using South for my database migrations:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    db.add_column('group', 'schedule',
        self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')\
        (to=orm['app.Schedule'], blank=True, null=True)\
    )
```

The view is pretty simple:

```
def api_group(jsonDict, request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #other handlers
        elif operation == "edit":
            _update_group(request)

def _update_group(request):
    group = Group.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('id'))
    formData = request.POST.copy()
    form = GroupForm(formData, instance=group)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

class GroupForm(renderutils.BaseModelForm):
    id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta(renderutils.BaseModelForm.Meta):
        model = Group
```

When I look at the 'group' table, I can see the field named 'schedule_id' and correct values are getting assigned on save, I just don't understand why the error is being raised if nothing is going wrong?  I've tried doing a backward and forward south migration multiple times to make sure it wasn't something wrong with it.